# How to force Drupal search.module find "111-222" page by searching "111 222"?

Tags: search

How to force Drupal search.module find "111-222" page by searching request "111 222" ?
For instance I have page example.com/111-222
about something, named 111-222
How to force Drupal to think that minus "-" and space is the same?

P.S. Famous search.module code modifications for partial search 
( $query2 = substr(str_repeat("i.word LIKE '%%%s%%' OR ", count($arguments2)), 0, -4);
etc) is already applied.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API for search, it would seem that [hook_search_preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_preprocess/7) will allow you to alter the way keywords are extracted, something like this:

```
function mymodule_search_preprocess($text) {
  return preg_replace('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', '$1 $2', $text);
}
```

I haven't tested this code, it's purely meant as a sample. It assumes your "words" are all digits as per the question.

Answer (score 0):

The solr module provides an interface to altering the query. Switch to this search engine and create this in an otherwise blank module - called solrmods in this case:

```
function solrmods_apachesolr_modify_query(&$query, &$params, $caller) {
  $pattern = '/([^\s])-/';
  $replacement = '${1} ';
  $keys_escape_hyphen = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $query->get_keys()); 
  $query->set_keys($keys_escape_hyphen);
}
```

Be careful that Solr is probably set to using dismax query parser and '-' may mean exclude this from the query. This is just to be aware of this as the drupal solr module assumes this and changing it will probably just confuse it. There are other options in solr - you can filter characters there too using java. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Other_built-in_useful_query_parsers

Comment: Thank you for reply, Interlated! If I know properly - for using Solr search engine it should be installed separately? There is can be found solve except using shell? I am hosted on virtual sharing, without any shell access, only Panel.

Comment: You can use a hosted solr service. Last we used was solr.midwesternmac.com. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219354/apache-solr-as-a-service-hosting